# Email Recipient List truncated using UTL_MAIL or UTL_SMTP

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have an issue where the email recipient list is getting truncated in OUTLOOK It just show 240 - 260 characters in the TO field whether I use UTL_MAIL or UTL_SMTP .It was all working fine till last month end.I am not sure must have changed.I tried putting my email and remaining 70+ fake emails to test,but it just shows 8 to 9 email in Outlook.

Although the email is being sent to all 80+ recipients as I did a test in lower environment.

I found the below reference but no solution

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/100041/email-recipieny-list.html

used code :

```
DECLARE
vemail VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG(email,';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY email) INTO vemail FROM

 (SELECT 'raa@nyc.org' email FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 'raa'||LEVEL||'@nyc.org' FROM dual connect BY LEVEL < 80
 );
      utl_mail.send (sender      => 'test@nyc.org',
                          recipients   => vemail,
                          cc           => NULL,
                          bcc          => NULL,
                          subject      => 'TESTING',
                          message      => 'TESTING',
                          mime_type    => 'text/html; charset=us-ascii');

END;
```

Comment: Please show use your code.

Comment: @wernfried-domscheit  Surprisingly I changed the semicolon to comma when i concatenate email and now it shows all the emails in the outlook. But it is so weird the code was working with ; for last so many years and now I have to concatenate emails with comma.

Comment: @wernfried-domscheit  added used code

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the concatenation of email from semicolon to comma and it worked. But why would it happen is still mystery. The semicolon code was working for many years and all the emails were getting displayed in Outlook To field.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/187218/space-a-valid-delimiter-for-email-addresses-in-email-header